# What is the remainder of $\frac{55^{75}×93^{175}×107^{275}}{17}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> What is the remainder of the following?
>   $$\dfrac{55^{75}×93^{175}×107^{275}}{17}$$

My solution:

The remainder of $\dfrac{55^{75}}{17}$ is $13$.

The remainder of $\dfrac{93^{175}}{17}$ is $15$.

The remainder of $\dfrac{107^{275}}{17}$ is $6$.

Finally, the remainder of $\dfrac{13×15×6}{17}$ is $14$, which must be the solution.

> Please suggest whether this is correct.

Comment: You can use [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=55%5E75+*+93%5E175+*+107%5E275+mod+17) for this. There's no reason to bother us with this.

Comment: Can you explain how you got to any of your claims and how  your claims lead to your answer?

Answer (score 2):

Say that $a$ leaves a remainder of $x$ and $b$ leaves a remainder of $y.$ So, we can write

$$a = 17n + x,$$
$$b = 17m + y.$$

Thus,

$$ab = (17n+x)(17m+y) = 17^2nm + 17(ny + mx) + xy,$$

so $ab$ leaves the same remainder as $xy$ when you divide it by $17.$

Luckily for you, you have a product and you've computed the remainder of each individual term--so you can just multiply them, as you did, to get the remainder that the entire product leaves.